# Restore mysqldump that created using --no-create-info and want to skip tables that not present in current database

Tags: mysql

I have a mysqldump backup that was created using `--no-create-info`  option. I want to restore it to a new database that does not have certain tables (approximately  50 tables remove from target database as they were no longer needed).

So I am getting `Table 'table_name' doesn't exist` for the obvious reason.

So what is the `mysql` way of restoring to a database that does not have all the tables present in backup file.

I may user `--insert-ignore` to avoid this failure but I doubt this may also ignore some genuine errors such as data type mismatch etc.

Comment: Err Doubt you can get mysql to ignore the fact you are trying to restore to non-existant tables. Or did I misunderstand

Comment: Is this a "If I had some Ham, we could have Ham and Eggs, if I had some Eggs" type question?

Comment: @RiggsFolly- Suppose I have a backup of  the database that was having 100 tables but my new database have only 50 tables.

Comment: Is the backup is SQL format?

Comment: Yes. Insert statements

Comment: Then edit out those tables you dont want

Comment: Look at the data type mismatches and decide why they are happening and fix the database or the data depending on why

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert rows to a table that doesn't exist, obviously.

To restore the data in your dump file, you need to create those tables first. You could go back to your source MySQL instance and dump those table definitions with `mysqldump --no-data`

If you don't care about the data, and you only want to restore data for tables that do exist, then you could filter out the INSERT statements before trying to import that script.

You could use `grep -v` for example to eliminate the rows.

Or you could use `sed` to delete lines between "-- Dumping data for table `tablename`" and whatever the next table is.

If you don't want to filter the data but you don't care about restoring data for the tables that don't exist, you could create dummy tables with the right fields, but define the tables with the [BLACKHOLE storage engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blackhole-storage-engine.html), so the INSERTs won't actually result in saving any data.

One more option: Import the dump file with `mysql --force` so it continues even if it gets errors on some of the INSERTs.